# I am unable to get past the login page in my identityserver4 ui

Tags: security, .net-core, xss, identityserver4, filterattribute

I am using `IdentityServer4` with my `.NET Core` project, have added the IdentityServer4 UI dependencies using `iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/release/get.ps1'))` in my command line.

And this added the UI defaults successfully, however when login in from the UI, i am only redirected back to the login page of `IdentityServer4` . I noticed some CSP filter attributes have been added by default (`[SecurityHeaders]`).

When i remove this attribute from my Grants controller, I am getting through to the `Grants` page as I imagined, now I know this is there to protect against Cross Site Scripting and Sniffing.

My question is how do I have this `SecurityHeadersAttribute` in there as still get redirected to the `Grants` controller successfully for a successful login.

**Test Data Used**

```
public static class ApiRecourses
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Get()
    {
        return new ApiResource[]
        {
            new ApiResource("testresource", "testresourcedisplayname")
        };
    }
}

public static class Clients
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "testclient",
                ClientName = "testclientname",
                ClientSecrets = new Secret[]
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>() {"testresource"},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials
            }
        };
    }
}


    public static IEnumerable<TestUser> Get()
    {
        return new TestUser[]
        {
            new TestUser()
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "a@b.c",
                Password = "password"
            }
        };
    }
```

**ConfigureServices**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var pfxFilePath = Configuration.GetSection("Certificate:PfxFilePath");
        var pfxFilePassword = Configuration.GetSection("Certificate:Password");

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath.Value, pfxFilePassword.Value))
            .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiRecourses.Get())
            .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Get().ToList());

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**Configure**

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Comment: Give some more details about your entire setup (IDS, clients etc.). Also if you show some more code, around their configuration, will be useful

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 I have added the test data used. hope that helps

Comment: OK something here is not ok. Your client is ResourceOwnerClientCredentials. This grant type is for api's (or console apps or whatever). How are you getting to the Identity Server login page?